# jQuery Mobile timepicker: How to enable 15-minute step?

Tags: jquery-mobile, custom-controls, timepicker

this is my first question on Stackoverflow, so please don't hate me for missing anything :)

I am currently trying to build a Phonegap application using jQuery Mobile.

At this point I'm having issues handling Time inputs. I need the input to only offer 15-minute steps. I've tried the **[DateBox plugin](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/)** which offers this functionality. My code looks as follows:

```html
<input name="txtAfzEnde" id="txtAfzEnde" type="text" data-role="datebox"
 data-options='{"mode":"timeflipbox", "minuteStep":"15", "useFocus":true}' />
```

However on an iPhone it's not possible to switch to this input using the "Prev/Next" Buttons.

#### So my question is:

Is it possible to use the standard HTML-inputs like

```html
<input name="mytime" id="mytime" type="time" />
```

with any customizing options to use a 15-minute step? I'm imagining something like:

```html
<input name="mytime" id="mytime" type="time" data-options='{"minuteStep":"15"}'/>
```

I'd like it to use the native timepicker so it integrates well with the other UI elements.

If something like this is not possible, please suggest a plugin that allows me to customize it in the needed way and also integrates well with native UI inputs.

Greets,
Philip

Comment: Can you elaborate on why " on an iPhone it's not possible to switch to this input using the "Prev/Next" Buttons"?  Maybe we could help you get the plugin to work on an iPhone.

Comment: I am not sure as to why exactly it is not possible. The buttons simply A) don't show up if you tap the DateBox-Time input field and B) if you tap another (native) input field and hit the "Next" button that sits on top of the iPhone keyboard it will skip the DateBox-Time input fields.

Comment: It's because, by default, datebox marks the input on the page as read only - in order to force the use of the popup control (otherwise you user could type whatever they like into the field)

Comment: Does either of you have any suggestions as to what I can do about that? Is there any way to tell the native control elements to only show hours and the minutes 0,15,30,45? I'd be very grateful for your help.

Comment: @Philip did you manage to do this?